# Showing that flux fluctuation is $q^2 P_n(q)/2\pi$

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, astronomy, fourier-transform

In the context of spectral analysis of a sufficiently small section of the sky, [1](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-637X/769/1/68) states that the flux fluctuation is given by $q^2 P_n(q)/2\pi$ on the angular scale of wavelength $2\pi/q$, where $P_n(q)$ is the power associated with the multipole $q$.

I was wondering how I could show that relation? Any insight or reference would be greatly appreciated.